# system.out of object to string

Tags: java, joptionpane, string-concatenation, system.out

Very new to Java so all help is appreciated, but please give the more direct answer possible.

I am trying to change a System.out.println statement to one that will be displayed in a JOptionPane. This is my first attempt at GUI, and find myself hopelessly lost.

I have Strings being printed through several methods in order to display one snippet of output. The part of the output I want to go in one pane, so I think the easiest way might be to concatenate a string.

I have an ArrayList  hard that holds a Card value. I overloaded the toString method in Card for the ranks, and the Suit enum that the Card uses returns Strings ("Heart", Spade", etc.)

```
for(int x = 0; x < hand.size(); x++){
    System.out.println(hand.get(x));
} //correctly prints the code
```

I was trying to do 
        String handString = "";

```
    for(int x = 0; x < hand.size(); x++){
        handString = handString.concat(hand.get(x)); //also tried concat(toString(hand.get(x))
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to change the Card toString and why it prints to the console, but why I can't put it to a string? I have a feeling this is very obvious but nothing I can find online seems to help with my combination of enums and class objects.

Also, how would I go about turning several printings to the console to one printing in a JOptionPane?

Comment: The way to concatenate something to the end of a string is `handString += hand.get(x);`. The `+` operator does concatenation when applied to strings.

Comment: I want to add that I am concatenating because I want it to print each card on a separate line in the JOptionPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
for(int x = 0; x < hand.size(); x++){
   handString += hand.get(x);
   handString += "\n"; 
}
```

The plus(+) operator takes care of conversion to String (using the toString() method for objects - which you have overriden).

You can also use the foreach loop here (much shorter, personal preference though):

```
for (Card card : hand) {
    handString += card;
    handString += "\n";
}
```

Comment: I want each card to display on a different line. For example: "Ace of Hearts\n2 of Diamonds" and yes, the enhanced for loop was the way to go, but I'm less familiar with them at the moment so I wanted to make it as direct for myself as possible.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a return after each card toString. As I mentioned the foreach usage is personal preference. :)

Comment: But I do suggest you look into foreach (used as norm in Java), first have a look at iterator and foreach explanation will follow.

Comment: Thank You SOOOOO much nash_ag. It worked. I can't believe I didn't come across that in my research online. When I looked at the Oracle site toString said that it could have been used on objects. Where did I go wrong and why did this work while that didnt?

Comment: Glad could help :)
I would suggest looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29
It takes a string, not an object (no toString conversion). Where as + has toString conversion for objects (mentioned in the same link - introduction).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explicitly call `.toString()` on the Card-object:

```
for(int x = 0; x < hand.size(); x++){
    handString = handString.concat(hand.get(x).toString());
}
```

Afterwards, of course, you need to also update whatever is tied to `handString`.

---

Cleaner version:

```
for (Card c : hand) {
    handString += c;
}
```

Comment: You didn't have to call toString() on the Card-Object to `System.out.println` it because `System.out.println` accepts an `Object` and calls `toString()` internally.